# List assigned issues of a GitHub project (assigned to anyone, not just me)

Tags: github, issue-tracking, github-issues

In a GitHub project, how to **list all issues that are assigned**?
I mean assigned to anyone, not just issues assigned to *me*.

- Preferably from the oldest to the newest.
- Preferably as a web interface so that I can open the hyperlinks to unassign if appropriate.

## Context

My [GitHub project](https://github.com/commons-app/apps-android-commons/issues) liberally assigns issues to newcomers, allowing them to quickly start working on an issue while avoiding duplicating work.

Problem: Half of the newcomers silently disappear without fixing the issue, letting the issue assigned and thus hidden from other contributors looking for an unassigned one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start first with using [`gh issue list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_issue_list)

```
gh issue list --assignee='*'
```

When [listing repository issues](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-repository-issues), the "`*`" for issues assigned to any user.

---

The [OP Nicolas Raoul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226958/nicolas-raoul) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76041717/list-assigned-issues-of-a-github-project-assigned-to-anyone-not-just-me/76098363#comment134374836_76098363):

> Based on that I now use `assignee:* sort:updated-asc` in GitHub.com's web UI search bar, it works great!
> Example:
>
> https://github.com/commons-app/apps-android-commons/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+assignee%3A*+sort%3Aupdated-asc

Comment: Based on that I now use `assignee:* sort:updated-asc` in GitHub.com's web UI search bar, it works great! Example: https://github.com/commons-app/apps-android-commons/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+assignee%3A%2A+sort%3Aupdated-asc

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Great! Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.